# An element with any type of child elements except empty string

Tags: xsd-validation

I have very little knowledge in xsd and in an urgent need for a solution to a petty problem.
I need to define an element(named tag) which may have any type and number of child elements(and texts as well) but must not contain an empty string.
Example: <tag1> co<sub1>2</sub1> <b1>laser</b1></tag1>,<tag1>co2</tag1>,<tag1><i1>laser</i1></tag1> are allowed (let's say that even <tag1><i1></i1></tag1> is also allowed). But <tag1></tag1> not allowed. Please let me know if there is a very simple way of doing this.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using XSD 1.1, you can use an assertion to check the condition you describe:

```
<xs:element name="tag" type="non-empty"/>
<xs:complexType name="non-empty"> 
  <xs:sequence minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded">
    <xs:any/>
  </xs:sequence>
  <xs:assert test="child::* or not(string(.) eq '')"/>
</xs:complexType>
```

In XSD 1.0, there isn't quite such a simple approach; if I were you and working in XSD 1.0, I'd change the design to something easier to express in XSD 1.0.

In 1.0, it's easy to require that the `tag` element have one or more children, without constraining the children:

```
<xs:complexType name="non-empty" mixed="true">
  <xs:sequence minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="unbounded">
    <xs:any/>
  </xs:sequence>
</xs:complexType>

<xs:element name="tag" type="non-empty"/>
```

It's also easy to specify that the `tag` element can have any non-empty string (I'm taking you at your word here, and allowing strings consisting only of white space -- be careful what you ask for):

```
<xs:simpleType name="non-empty">
  <xs:restriction base="xs:string">
    <xs:minLength value="1"/>
  </xs:restriction>
</xs:simpleType>

<xs:element name="tag" type="non-empty"/>
```

What's not possible in 1.0 is (a) declaring an element as having either a simple or a complex type, or (b) constraining the textual content of a complex type with mixed content.

Good luck.